# Taking an element of An ArrayList and passing it as an argument

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I am having a bit of a hiccup with this ArrayList. I am trying to store one or more elements from a String array into an Array list and assigning it to some string variable. My goal is to store keywords into an array list which i could use to search a text file. I can't seem to store found keywords into the array list  Can someone help me figure this issue out? Here's some snippets from my code.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException        
    {
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] keywords = {"day", "book", "office", "hour",
        "date of a test", "number of assignments", "sure",
        "current assignment", "due day"};
     System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

        System.out.print("> ");
        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

         int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            if (input.contains(keywords[i])) {


            matches.add(keywords[i]);

                parseFile(keywords[i]);
    }
}

  }
```

And here is my parseFile method

```
     public static void parseFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile);
            // break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Please be more specific.

Comment: In your comment, you ask how do you store the keywords in a string -What is the format you want the string to have?

Comment: Depends on how you want the `String` to be formatted. You can use a `StringBuilder` and just append each keyword there.. or you can just use `matches.toString()` at the end.

Comment: Since the question is still unclear, here are some suggestions to improve the code: you're calling parseFile(keywords[i]); for every match. This way you'll open the file and read through it multiple times, and it's unnecessary. Once you have the complete list of matches, you can give that as a parameter to parseFile. Also, close the file when you're done reading from it! Last, contains() will also match on substrings ("booking" contains "book") - is this what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the first things I'd do, is check that the stuff is actually going in to the array, so I'd have this:

```
if(matches.size() == 0)
{
    System.out.println("There's nothing in here");
}
```

That way at least you know that there's nothing there, so then there's no point doing the rest of the program.  You should always test your exit condition early where possible that way you save a bit of time, and energy, and allows for quicker debugging.  But I digress.

So to add the stuff in to the array list you'd need to do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) 
{
   String value = keywords[i];
   System.out.println("Current Value is: " + value);
   matches.add(value);
}
```

You can't just add an array element as the add method in ListArray is expecting a String.  So you need to set the current content of the array to a String then pass THAT in to your matches.add function as above, so when I ran that program on my box, (just the main bit that is) I got the following output.

```
Current Value is: day
Current Value is: book
Current Value is: office
Current Value is: hour
Current Value is: date of a test
Current Value is: number of assignments
Current Value is: sure
Current Value is: current assignment
Current Value is: due day
Size of matches is: 9
Matches[i]: day
Matches[i]: book
Matches[i]: office
Matches[i]: hour
Matches[i]: date of a test
Matches[i]: number of assignments
Matches[i]: sure
Matches[i]: current assignment
Matches[i]: due day
```

Also for the record, you need to do the same when you're iterating through your matches as well, so let's say you want to print out your ArrayList, then you'd need to do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
{
    String value = matches.get(i);
    System.out.println("Matches[i]: " + value);
}
```

You'd need to get the string within the array list, you can't just give it an index, as that will not work, again you need to assign it to a string and then pass that back.

If in doubt, dive on to the Java ArrayList API, and have a look at what arguments the functions take.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @ Welshboy Okay let's say I entered some text that contains  two matching keywords,How do i Store the two matching keywords in the list and retrieve them?

Comment: Why would you want to store two identical keywords though?  If you really wanted to keep two keywords, then I'd consider using a map, but it's been a few years since I've done a lot of Java, but I'd take a look at a map, e.g. map<int, String> where int is the key and the string is the value, have a look at that.  Hope it helps

Comment: No, I want to store the keywords if it is two keywords. Eg if "go" and "help" are two keywords, I want to store them and retrieve them. Understand?